# Select a TTS synthesis engine from the application programatically in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I installed 2 TTS Synthesis engines 1.PICO TTS and the other 2. SVOX Classic TTS. The default selected TSS engine will be used by the application. But, in our application we have to prompt him the user to select any of them if there are more than 1 TTS engines. I tried using 'TextToSpeech.EngineInfo.getEngines()' but it is showing errors as this class is declared as 'static'. Can U please help me in this in detail what to use exactly.
                                                 thank you...

Comment: `TextToSpeech.EngineInfo` is available starting from API version 14 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/package-summary.html